# Knapsack recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I have a list named self.items where the elements are:

```
items = [dict(id=0, w=4, v=12),
         dict(id=1, w=6, v=10),
         dict(id=2, w=5, v=8),
         dict(id=3, w=7, v=11),
         dict(id=4, w=3, v=14),
         dict(id=5, w=1, v=7),
         dict(id=6, w=6, v=9)]
```

With this I had to do a list of lists, where every element has all the possible combinations including the empty case, so finally my list of lists has more or less this appearence:

```
[[],[{id:0,w:4,v:12}],....,[{id:0,w:4,v:12}, {id:1,w:6,v:10}]....]
```

Now I have to found a recursive function to search what combination of elements has the max weight permitted and the max value.

```
 def recursive(self, n, max_weight):
""" Recursive Knapsack
:param n: Number of elements
:param max_weight: Maximum weight allowed
:return: max_value
"""
self.iterations += 1 
result = 0

if max_weight > self.max_weight: #they gave me self.max_weight as a variable of  __init__ method which shows me what is the maximum weight permitted
    self.recursive(self, self.items+self.iterations, max_weight)
    if max_weight < self.max_weight:
        self.recursive(self, self.items+self.iterations, max_weight)
    else:
            result = self.items['v']+result

return result
```

I think that my error is in this line:

```
result = self.items['v']+result
```

But I cannot find it.

Comment: What is the error you're getting?  What result did you expect?  What did you get?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, but it doesn't work. The result I expect is max_value=44 and I get max_value=0 This are the selected items that  sum 44 `Selected items:
[{'id': 0, 'w': 4, 'v': 12}, {'id': 1, 'w': 6, 'v': 10}, {'id': 2, 'w': 5, 'v': 8}, {'id': 4, 'w': 3, 'v': 14}]`
And this is the result of apply my code:
`Method: recursive
Iterations:1
Max value:0 expected max_value:44`

Answer (score 0):

I just have found the solution to this recursive problem:
(I'm from Spain so the variable "cantidad" also means "quantity")

```
 def recursive(self, n, max_weight):
    """ Recursive Knapsack
    :param n: Number of elements
    :param max_weight: Maximum weight allowed
    :return: max_valu
    """
    self.iterations += 1
    result = 0
    cantidad = 0
    quantity = 0

    if max_weight == 0 or n == 1:
        if  max_weight >= self.items[n-1]['w'] :
            cantidad= self.items[n-1]['v']

        return max(cantidad,quantity)
    else:
        if  max_weight >= self.items[n-1]['w']:
            cantidad = self.items[n-1]['v']+self.recursive(n-1,max_weight-self.items[n-1]['w'])

        quantity = self.recursive(n-1,max_weight)
        result = max(cantidad, quantity)
        return result
```

I put this code into a program proportioned by the university I am studying at and it returns to me the correct result:

```
Method: recursive
Iterations:107
Max value:44 expected max_value:44
```